# Проблемы с переопределения когда добавляю переменные в метод Swift

Tags: swift, функции, переменные, методы, переопределение

Хочу в переопределенным методе, добавить переменные, но мне компилятор выдает ошибку, что надо сделать в коде, что он их принял.

```
 class Z{
func zoo(x:String) {
 print("Hel-\(x)") 
} 
}
class X:Z{
override func zoo(x:String) {
 super.zoo(x:x)
 var z:Int=0

 print("Hello-\(x) \(z)")
}
} 
let s=X() 
s.zoo("\(x:"Mir") \(z:24)")﻿
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Z{
    func zoo(x:String) {
        print("Hel-\(x)")
    }
}
class X:Z{
    func zoo(x:String, z:Int) {
        print("Hello-\(x) \(z)")
    }
}
let s=X()

s.zoo(x: "Mir", z:24)
s.zoo(x: "Mir")
```

методы с одинаковым названием, но разными параметрами не переопределяются, а считаются разними методами.

Comment: ...и называется это [**перегрузка**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за новые знание !!!! СЛАВА БОГУ !!!!